# Filtering a Scala Multimap and outputting as a list of Tuples

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tuples, multimap

I have a map using the multimap trait, like so
`val multiMap = new HashMap[Foo, Set[Bar]] with MultiMap[Foo, Bar]`
I would like to combine filtering this map on specific values
`multiMap.values.filter(bar => barCondition)`
with flattening the matching results into a list of tuples of the form
`val fooBarPairs: List[(Foo, Bar)]`
What would be the idiomatic way of doing this? I was hoping that Scala might provide something like an anamorphism to do this without looping, but as a complete newbie I am not sure what my options are.

Comment: If a foo maps to a set of bars that all satisfy the filter predicate, should the resulting list contains tuples (foo, bar) for all the bars? It would be helpful if you gave some illustrating examples.

Comment: In my question "Matching results" was meant to specify that I was only interested in Bars that passed the filter criteria, sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
import collection.mutable.{HashMap, MultiMap, Set}

val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[Int]] with MultiMap[String, Int]
mm.addBinding("One", 1).addBinding("One",11).addBinding("Two",22).
  addBinding("Two",222)
  // mm.type = Map(Two -> Set(22, 222), One -> Set(1, 11))
```

I think the easiest way to get what you want is to use a for-expression:

```
for {
  (str, xs) <- mm.toSeq
  x         <- xs
  if x > 10
} yield (str, x)      // = ArrayBuffer((Two,222), (Two,22), (One,11))
```

You need the `.toSeq` or the output type will be a `Map`, which would mean each mapping is overidden by subsequent elements. Use `toList` on this output if you need a `List` specifically.

Comment: I like it, sequence comprehension fits this problem nicely.

Comment: No need for a `toSeq` if you use `collection.breakOut`.

Comment: @Debilski Intrigued. Can you use `breakOut` in for-expressions? Or just when you de-sugar it to something like @mhs's answer.

Comment: `(for {...} yield ())(breakOut) : List[(String, Int)]` should indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I think you want to do:

```
scala> mm
res21: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]] with scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[String,Int]
= Map(two -> Set(6, 4, 5), one -> Set(2, 1, 3))

scala> mm.toList.flatMap(pair =>
         pair._2.toList.flatMap(bar =>
           if (bar%2==0)
             Some((pair._1, bar))
           else
             None))

res22: List[(String, Int)] = List((two,6), (two,4), (one,2))
```

Comment: That is helpful, I hadn't considered doing that two level breakdown. I'm only using the matching types so I guess I'd have to filter the None types again with this. It seems like a good general solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another, slightly more concise solution:

```
import collection.mutable.{HashMap, MultiMap, Set}

val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[Int]] with MultiMap[String, Int]
val f = (i: Int) => i > 10

mm.addBinding("One", 1)
  .addBinding("One",11)
  .addBinding("Two",22)
  .addBinding("Two",222)
  /* Map(Two -> Set(22, 222), One -> Set(1, 11)) */

mm.map{case (k, vs) => vs.filter(f).map((k, _))}.flatten
  /* ArrayBuffer((Two,222), (Two,22), (One,11)) */
```

Comment: Filtering then rebuilding the map seems like a good way to solve this, I'd give you points if I could. I did need the result as a list rather than the iterator given by the flatten function though.